# Obtain current page name in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: c#, xaml, mono, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently trying to understand how to get the name of the (xaml) page I am currently into, with my Xamarin Form app.

How am I supposed to do it? I tried a variety of cases, even looking around the Internet, but nothing actually worked for me so far :/

Comment: What do you mean by "name"?  The name of the page's class?  The name assigned in the XAML?  Or the Title property?

Comment: The name assigned in the XAML, like, MainPage.xaml, I'd like to obtain in output "MainPage"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is just C# reflection - the name of the XAML page should match the name of it's class

```
var name = this.GetType ().Name;
```

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous, thanks for the help, that was one of the few codes I didn't even think about trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You would (commonly) use wither a one page app (master/detail, tabs page) or a set of navigable pages, managed by a NavigationPage. 
`App.Current.MainPage` would (normally) contain the first page shown and if it has `.Navigation` that would be the NavigationPage that can give you the most recently shown page - last one in the stack. If it doesn't you could assume your app being one page app.

All of the above is just "common" and not necessarily true in all cases, but gives you a starting point where to look for your current page.

```
var actionPage = App.Current.MainPage;
if (actionPage.Navigation != null)
    actionPage = actionPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
actionPage.DisplayActionSheet(...)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ added a bit of description

Comment: This helped me with determining if an `SizeChanged` event should run, since it should only run when it's the top page. When looking at `this`, it's always that class because it's the class that has the event, so Jason's answer only works if you don't know the class that ran your method. When it's an event, it'll likely always be the same class the method is in.

Answer (score 12):

I know that this has been resolved and the scenario is somewhat different but in my specific case I needed to identify the current page in the navigation stack from platform specific code so just in case it may help someone else, this is the code I used:

I used the title property that was set in the constructor of the page.

```
public static string GetCurrentPage()
        {
            var page = App.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
            return page.Title;
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get current open page.

1) **if it's MainPage.**
-> var MainPage = App.Current.MainPage as PageName;

2) **if it's Navigation page**.

you can get count pages.

App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count

```
var page= App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault() as 

PageName;
```

App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count

```
var page1=App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault() as 
PageName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get the current page type from anywhere in the app (`Xamarin Forms`).

This might be a more general answer to your question but I thought it's worth posting.

If you're using:

### 1.App with Tabs/One Page

```
var mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as Xamarin.Forms.Shell;
var currentPage = mainPage.CurrentPage;
var type = currentPage.GetType().Name;
```

Also, URL of the current page:

```
string location = mainPage.CurrentState.Location.ToString()
```

### 2.Navigation Based Apps

As others also mentioned:

```
var mainPage = App.Current.MainPage;
var currentPage = mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same requirement, none of the solutions shown here worked for me, I tried this:

```
var mainpage = App.Current.MainPage as Shell;
var currentpage = mainpage.CurrentPage;
```

and it finally worked!